# How to do commenting within Facebook App

Tags: facebook

I am going to be doing a small Facebook page/app for a university that will have several different a canvas page of content from my server. They also want Facebook commenting within these pages.

I have looked into how to put commenting on these pages and have two options:

- Programmatically adding it with API calls using the PHP SDK
- Using the Social Plugin for comments

Programming it will do full functionality I need but is very time consuming and not with all Facebook styling (unless replicated with CSS).

The [Comments Social Plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) is exactly what I need because it has all the Facebook styling and functionality built in. Only drawback is the fact the wizard asks for a URL, which leads me to believe it's not meant for apps.

**Is this the best thing to be using within a Facebook app?** It seems to be meant for external sites and doesn't mention using on a app.

FBML looks like it was what I required but this is being deprecated next year so I am going to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Go with the plugin. You can use the url of your app or of your page tab, whatever you have. If you want to be sure, just insert the url into the generator ([here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)), click on *get code* and see below your comments plugin. Wasn't that easy? : ]

Comment: Would be good if they mentioned using them on apps, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

The provided social widgets from Facebook are only offered for static URL's however you can add your own code for dynamic pages so that the widget will be purely be for the URL the user is at.

i.e

```
<fb:comments href="<?php echo $currentUrl; ?>" num_posts="2" width="500" style="padding-top: 20px; margin-top: 20px; border-top: 1px dotted grey;"></fb:comments>
```

Something such as that.

Comment: It says on the docs that fbml is being deprecated as of next jan.

Comment: Whilst Facebook still offer XFBML mark-up for their widgets on their official config pages to build your code, then it is perfectly fine to use this. If they depreciate any language, then they will make the transition to something new (HTML 5) as simple as possible. Perhaps read this - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments_(XFBML)/ which allows you to build and test your config for use in an app.

Comment: If you look at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/ read what it says at the top. Seems a bit pointless doing something that will last 1-6 months before requiring an update.